# A person who has no way to escape is in a _______ situation

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose a well is in front of a person and a ditch behind him. He is in danger of falling into any one of the two. There is no way to escape  for him because  he  has  to  go  a  head  despite  the  risk  involved .He  has to  choose between  the two  choices.

In fact the above situation is taken from an idiom.

We can say that he is in a ________ situation.

What is the proper word to fill in the blank?

I  am  expecting  an  adjective  other than dangerous, inescapable, precarious, and helpless. I am thinking of   a different word.

Could you please find the right word for me?

Comment: Between a rock and a hard place?

Comment: Also, this is the very definition of the word *dilemma.*

Comment: You say "There is no way to escape", but later on "The situation is not inescapable". So which do you mean?

Comment: If you're keen to find an adjective to pair with "situation", you might look at "precarious" or "sticky"

Comment: He is in an impossible situation.

Comment: Why are dangerous, inescapable, precarious, and helpless not suitable?

Comment: @Taliesin  Merlin.They  are  all  possible.But  I  would  like  to  use   the  most  apt  word  which  I May  not  know.I  know  that  he  is  in  a  state  of  delemma or  fix

Comment: `dead-end` situation? Does that make sense?

Comment: I guess I don't know why a word like **inescapable** is not the most apt way to describe a situation with *no way to escape*. There seems to be an embedded assumption that I don't understand.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The word you are looking for is -

## Dilemma

> A situation in which a difficult choice has to be made between two or
> more alternatives, especially ones that are equally undesirable.

(From [Lexico](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/dilemma))

---

Therefore, you can say that -

> [John] is in a ***dilemmatic*** situation.

Answer (score -2):

There are many words that could be used and some of them you have listed, and others have been listed by commenters. (I'm sorry, Justin, but I've never heard dilemma used in this way and it just sounds wrong! Of course 'John is in a dilemma' is quite right but that doesn't answer in the form Englishmonger is asking for. [Edit: Justin notes that his answer is correct. I should have noted that it is and my comments about it were an argument from ignorance.])

Yet more options include: no-win, loosing, bad, ridiculous, difficult, and many more. If you have one particular word in mind any clue would be useful. One way is to plug any of the suggestions so far in a thesaurous (e.g. [this one](https://www.thesaurus.com/), or many others on-line) and see what they suggest.

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/dilemmatic - *Dilemmatic* is another form of *dilemma*.

Comment: @Justin Yes. I should have noted that the form looked right. However I have never heard or seen it before - and yes, again, that was an argument from ignorance.

Comment: Look it up. You'll get many instances of it being used. And since the word *does* exist, I don't see why it shouldn't be used here.  (https://journals.sfu.ca/flr/index.php/journal/article/view/83/184)